# Convert regression coefficient from fixed effects model to percentage increase

Tags: r, fixed-effects-model, difference-in-difference

I'm running the following fixed-effect model in R:

`felm(DV ~ treatment*intervention | week + participant | 0 | participant_id)`

i.e., I'm controlling for the fixed effect of `week` and `participant`, and clustering the standard error by `participant`. `treatment` is an indicator variable for treatment (1 = treatment, 0 = control), and `intervention` is an indicator variable for whether the observation is from intervention period or not (1 = during intervention, 0 = pre-intervention). The unit of `DV` is the number of visits.

The estimator of `treatment*intervention` would then tell me that "the treatment group made X more visits compared to the control during the intervention."

If I'd like to get a percentage increase, however, such that I can say that "the treatment group made X% more visits compared to the control", what should I do? Should I grab the model-predicted DV for control preintervention, control intervention, treatment preintervention, treatment intervention, and calculate percentage change, or is there a better way to deal with this?

Comment: Can you log the outcome? Or are there many zero visits?

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov yes, there are a lot of zero visits so can't log the outcome

Comment: A quick hack would be to replace zero by epsilon and then log. A Poisson FE model with clustered errors would be another option.